# Throw DmlException and getDmlMessage

Tags: apex, exception, error-messages

I need to throw DMLException and get message via getDmlMessage. But it gives me error for any message of DMLException on getDmlMessage. And I can't find any code about constructor parameters. Ide offlineSymbolTable says its string or exception, but both gives me error. How can I set right message? And there are any detailed documentation?  Here is sample code

```
try {
    DmlException ex = new DmlException();
    ex.setMessage('123');
    throw ex; 
} catch (DmlException e) {
   System.debug( e.getDmlMessage(0));
}
```

Error on line 7, column 1: System.UnexpectedException: 123